# SCCM 2007 + FEP 2010 deployment - when can I upgrade sql server?

Tags: system-center, microsoft-forefront-2010

I am in the process of migrating our forefront client security installation on the domain over to a forefront endpoint protection based on system center configuration manager 2007 platform.

I have installed SCCM 2007 and FEP 2010. I am still on sql 2005 as this was the version forefront client security used/supported but now sql 2005 is very outdated. I would like to upgrade to 2008R2 sql server. Is there any specific reason I would not be able to do this?

I tried to find information regarding sql server upgrade mentioned under either product on technet but I did not find anything specific to FEP2010 or SCCM2007. I also looked for this info in the deployment guide. I am not sure how to interpret the info not being there. Meaning it could be so incredibly simple of a process it did not require an article, or it could be quite troublesome. After the fight I had getting both products to install to w2k3 server I do not want to break what I have.

I realize I should have upgraded before installing either product but I wanted to provide a method to roll back if I had an issue getting SCCM2007 or FEP2010 installed. Now that they are in the most opportune time to upgrade is now I believe.

Thanks for any input.